# How do I edit a password protected .pf file

Tags: password-protection, libreoffice

I want to print selected pages from a Microchip PIC data sheet which is in .pdf format, with 436 pages, so printing it all out would use up an awful lot of paper and ink. I would like to open it with LibreOffice and use that to remove most of the pages from the copy. With, in Linux, "bookbinder" software I would convert the result into two other .pdf files, backs and fronts of the sheets, which I can then print out, with four A5 sized pages per A4 sheet, ending up with a nice little booklet with just the information I want to refer to.

I have no intention of doing any other editing to affect the original document, nor will I be attempting to sell any of it or make money from it, so this seems an innocent wish. Please is there a way to do it?

Comment: I think this question is offtopic for SO, but have a look at [pdftk server](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/), a command line utility that allows you to decompose a pdf into separate pages and recompose these pages to a new pdf.  Seems a lot easier than wading through 436 pages and doing tons of cut 'n paste work.

Comment: Thank you @fvu, I followed your suggestion, but pdftk won't open the file either, because of the password protection. Nice try.

Comment: From [the doc](http://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-man-page/#dest-input-pw) : `Most pdftk features require that encrypted input PDF are accompanied by the ~owner~ password. If the input PDF has no owner password, then the user password must be given, instead. If the input PDF has no passwords, then no password should be given.`  So, you will first need to use one of the (many) available tools or services to get rid of the owner password.  I just tried it, `pdftk A=22067J.unlocked.pdf cat a1-5 output out.pdf` on some random microchip datasheet worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @fvu for your suggestions. In the meantime I have found a solution that works for me. I simply `print` the locked file to another `.pdf` file, using the printer software, and the destination file is identical but unlocked. I can open it in LibreOffice Writer, and I could edit it if I wished.

To do what I really want, that is to extract some of the data, I can set up the print job to include just the pages I need, so the file size can be kept to a minimum. No need to involve LibreOffice or any other software for this task.

The process is simple, and probably no more complex than any other method would be.